# Use image as item in menu for Navigation Menu Drawer

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-view, android-navigationview

I'm creating a project with Navigation Drawer Menu in Android, however, so far the menu only shows an icon and title in the menu.

How do I change the whole menu item to become an image with text inside?

Currently: the menu is:

[image]

However, I would prefer it to be like this:

[image]

Comment: You may use Recyclerview and set custom layout in drawer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`NavigationView#addHeaderView(View)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View)) API and provide your custom view as a content of `NavigationView`.

The alternative is to use `app:headerLayout="@layout/your_layout"` through xml.

Comment: From these `app:headerLayout="@layout/your_layout"` we can change `Headerview`. but what about data listing?

Comment: Within `your_layout` you show everything. both header image and the list of items.

Comment: Thanks, even though it's not straightforward like other answer, but save me from creating new recyclerviews and new adapter

Answer (score 2):

You should use listview or recycler view in your `NavigationView` like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/Mainheader"
            layout="@layout/nav_header" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/exp_navigationmenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

After that, set data in `Listview`.